# Javascript OOP - private/public methods

Tags: javascript, oop

Helo there,

just a quick question, I'm using a pseudo-classical pattern to create objects in JS and I was wondering how do I actually create a private method that is accessible only inside the object.

let's say I want to add a private method XY() to object Animal. Does this kind of pattern allow me to create a private method?

```
function Animal(name) {
  this.name = name
}

Animal.prototype = {
  canWalk: true,
  sit: function() {
    this.canWalk = false
    alert(this.name + ' sits down.')
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Alex

Comment: You do this with [privileged functions](http://javascript.crockford.com/private.html).

Comment: @Jack perhaps you could include a link in that for OP to read up on privileged functions?

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.

Comment: apologies for a duplicate question.

Comment: private methods make no sense when anyone can add a method onto an instance that can call the so-called private method...